# How can i get the size of the status bar for any apple watch in swfit ui?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

this question here [Apple Watch: Status bar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817317/apple-watch-status-bar-height?rq=2) is very similar to what im asking for however that was 7 years ago, and seems to be for objective C, i need to get this information in swift ui view, is that even posible to get using a watchOs target?

i tried using WKInterfaceDevice but no information about the size or even the model i can find to guess the actual status bar size

Comment: You say “this question”, but there’s no link to a question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817317/apple-watch-status-bar-height?rq=2 IM SORRY i jsut missed the link, this is the one